# Discriminant analysis in R: how to obtain the threshold weight

Tags: r

I'm running a linear discriminant analysis with 2 variables and 2 groups in R, i.e.,

```
ldares <- lda(dat[,2:3], grouping=dat[,1])
```

Next, I would like to obtain the formula for the decision bound that separates the groups. I know that I can output the coefficients of the linear discriminant with:

```
coef(ldares)
```

However, given that the decision bound is described by:

```
a*v1 + b*v2 + c = 0,
```

how do I get the *bias* or *threshold weight* c?

Comment: Your code does not run, making it difficult for people to offer suggestions.  Also, perhaps ask on the statistics forum Cross Validated.

Answer (score 2):

When no prior weights are given, I believe you will discover that c=0 and that the discriminant scores are based on the distribution of the cases setting the priors. You can see that a score construction with an implicit c=0 assumption produces the expected split in prediction with the iris dataset:

```
require(MASS)
ldares <- lda(iris[ iris[,5] %in% c("setosa", "versicolor"),2:3], 
               grouping=iris[iris[,5] %in% c("setosa", "versicolor") ,5])
scores <- with( iris[ iris[,5] %in% c("setosa", "versicolor") , 2:3],
                 cbind(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length) %*% coef(ldares) )
with( iris[ iris[,5] %in% c("setosa", "versicolor") , c(2:3, 5)], 
              plot(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, col=c("black", "red")[1+(scores>0)])  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @DWin. It seems to me, though, that this is an incidental feature of the data set. Try running your code with a different data set, iris1, with:

`iris1 <- iris`
`iris1[,2] <- 10 + iris[,2]`
`iris1[,3] <- 10 + iris[,3]`

You will find that the coefficients are the same, but c is not 0. It has a values somewhere around 15.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the answer is: c is the midpoint between the two group means on the discriminant.

Comment: The answer from Lak address these concerns. There is a centering step so the c==0 point becomes the group mean. It is essentially removing the Intercept from a linear regression result.

Answer (score 0):

You should realize is that LDA is a linear combination of *centered* variables.  So, the discrimination function is really:

```
\Sigma [w * (x - mean(x))]  >  0
```

and therefore:

```
\Sigma [w * x]  >  \Sigma w * mean(x)
```

The threshold is therefore  \Sigma w * mean(x).  Unfortunately, LDA doesn't report mean(x) over the entire dataset, only the two group means.  But this allows us to compute the threshold in a rather intuitive way.

Assuming that result is your LDA result, the threshold is mid-way between the response to the centroids of the two classes:

```
> `sum( result$scaling * result$means[2,] + result$scaling * result$means[1,] )/2`
```

p.s. Note that in the original question `w1*a1 + w2*a2 + c = 0`,  the threshold is -c