# Interpreting negative LDA classifier scores

Tags: r, classification

The post 
[Classification functions in linear discriminant analysis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629550/classification-functions-in-linear-discriminant-analysis-in-r) 
from user Tyler provides a function to produce the classification functions (not discriminant functions!) from an LDA model generated with `lda()`.

I used these classification functions to calculate all classification scores for my data. I want to use the additional information e.g. to find out which was the second most probable class and to understand the development in different time slices

Now I would like to ask you for your help to interpret the following scenarios:

- scores close to/exactly zero (is it possible to claim that this exact class effectively was not recognized?)
- single negative scores of higher absolute value than highest positive value (Does it mean anything at all?)
- results with all negative scores (in the original interpretation, the highest score determines the classification. Is this intended by the LDA or does it mean that really none of the classifications is a good fit and one could say that no known pattern could be identified?)
- single very low positive values while all others are high absolute negative values (can I argue that the "signal strength" is low in this case?)

I know this is more of a statistical than a programming problem. I thought of it as a follow-up of the post at the beginning of this entry.
Thank you very much for your help!